# How can I set optional enum default value in protocol extension?

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

Here is a protocol 'Sortable' to describe sort, by and ascending. By is a unknown enum.

Sortable follows RawRepresentable, need implement from/to rawValue. the rawValue of the protocol is "(by.rawValue),(ascending.intValue)", but when i need get self from rawValue, "By(rawValue: Int(list[0]) ?? 0)" is a optional enum value, how can i offer a default enum value for it? I don't know the specific enum value. What i only know is "By: RawRepresentable where By.RawValue == Int"

```
protocol Sortable: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    associatedtype By: RawRepresentable where By.RawValue == Int
    
    var by: By { get set }
    var ascending: Bool { get set }
    
    init(by: By, ascending: Bool)
}

extension Sortable {
    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        let list = rawValue.split(separator: ",").compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : "\($0)" }
        guard list.count == 2 else { return nil }
        let by = By(rawValue: Int(list[0]) ?? 0) ??                      <===== HERE
        let ascending = Int(list[1])?.boolValue ?? true

        self.init(by: by, ascending: ascending)
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        return "\(by.rawValue),\(ascending.intValue)"
    }
}
```

UPDATE

I got a solution, add a "static var defaultBy: By { get }", but it's not so good. any idea?

```
protocol Sortable: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    associatedtype By: RawRepresentable where By.RawValue == Int
    
    var by: By { get set }
    var ascending: Bool { get set }
    static var defaultBy: By { get }
    
    init(by: By, ascending: Bool)
}

extension Sortable {
    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        let list = rawValue.split(separator: ",").compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : "\($0)" }
        guard list.count == 2 else { return nil }
        let by = By(rawValue: Int(list[0]) ?? 0) ?? Self.defaultBy
        let ascending = Int(list[1])?.boolValue ?? true

        self.init(by: by, ascending: ascending)
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        return "\(by.rawValue),\(ascending.intValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: So the rawValue parameter is supposed to contain 2 integers? Why not return nil (or better throw an error) if not both of them fulfill that requirement rather than having a default value?

Comment: Also, since the requirements are so specific why not create a struct that holds the two integer values?

Comment: "but it's not so good" In what way is it "not so good"?

Comment: @Sweeper, I think maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, this is a protocol, contain a enum and a bool. yes, struct AAA: Sortable {}, struct will have these 2 member too. return nil is good way. thanks!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's not a specific requirement. there are many struct comfort protocol Sortable, each have a enum by and a bool ascending, each struct has its own enum. some sort by name/time, some sort by height/age... So we need this protocol to define 2 members. RawRepresentable is for AppStorage, with it, we can save any Sortable struct instance into Usedefault using AppStorage.

Answer (score 0):

according to @Joakim Danielson suggestion, it's easy and nice!! thanks!!!

```
protocol Sortable: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    associatedtype By: RawRepresentable where By.RawValue == Int
    
    var by: By { get set }
    var ascending: Bool { get set }
    
    init(by: By, ascending: Bool)
}

extension Sortable {
    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        let list = rawValue.split(separator: ",").compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : "\($0)" }
        guard list.count == 2,
              let byInt = Int(list[0]), let by = By(rawValue: byInt),
              let ascendingInt = Int(list[1]) else { return nil }
        let ascending = ascendingInt.boolValue
        self.init(by: by, ascending: ascending)
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        return "\(by.rawValue),\(ascending.intValue)"
    }
}
```